# boto3 list_objects_v2 StartAfter does not work correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

While using list_objects_v2

> s3client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name,
>                                         StartAfter=starts_after)

from the boto3 package, I notice that if I use a key which is inside a folder in the bucket like

> bucket - 'some_bucket'
>
> key - 'adb/dcvf/staging0000.txt'

Then the StartAfter does not work properly and it returns the entire set of keys.

However if the keys are directly in the bucket without any folders like , then the StartAfter works perfectly.

> bucket - 'some_bucket'
>
> key - 'staging0000.txt'

Is this a known issue and are there any workarounds for this

Comment: Are you passing the full Key to `StartAfter`? That is, are you passing `adb/dcvf/staging0000.txt`? There should be no slash at the start. Also, your question is missing the second example -- feel free to Edit the Question to correct it.

Comment: @John Rotenstein  Sorry I could not get to this earlier. I have edited the question and yes, I don't pass the slash at the start

Answer (score 5):

**Version 2:**

It appears that your requirement is to **obtain a list of Keys of objects that have been added after a specific key timewise**.

This is not a suitable use for the `StartAfter` parameter, which merely lists keys that are alphabetically after the given string.

Instead, you would need to write a program that obtains a list of objects and then determines which keys you want, such as:

```
import boto3

client=boto3.client('s3',region_name='ap-southeast-2')

# Obtain a list of objects in the bucket
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')

# Make a dictionary of Key:Modified Date
objects = {object['Key']:object['LastModified'] for object in response['Contents']}

# Make a list of objects modified after a particular object
OBJECT_TO_COMPARE = 'foo.txt'
latest = [key for key in objects if objects[key] > objects[OBJECT_TO_COMPARE]]

# Print result
print ('\n'.join(latest))
```

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine for me...

```
import boto3

client=boto3.client('s3',region_name='ap-southeast-2')

# List all objects
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket')
print([o['Key'] for o in response['Contents']])

print('--------')

# List objects from foo/ onwards
response = client.list_objects_v2(Bucket='my-bucket', StartAfter='foo/')
print([o['Key'] for o in response['Contents']])
```

Comment: StartAfter is where you want Amazon S3 to start listing from. Amazon S3 starts listing after this specified key. I am trying to list the keys that has been added after a specific key. In your example you are not doing that

Comment: What do you mean by "added after a specific key"? Do you mean time-wise?

Comment: yes , I am looking for getting keys that has been added after a specific key timewise