# Quicker way to return files from S3 based on a pattern

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I have an S3 bucket and I want to return files only based on a pattern. All the files in the bucket has a date associated to it in the file name. For example the file name is `2023-10-18-edewj324lkj-34-sdf.ndjson`. I have a code that's returning the files I need but I was wondering if there is a better way or a faster way. To return 2400 files took about 4m30s.

I'm using AWS Glue

```
def findMissingFiles(bucket, curated_bucket, prefix, pattern):
    paginator = s3.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
    pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket = bucket, Prefix = prefix)
    TotalFilesInSrcBucket = set()
    for page in pages:
        for obj in page['Contents']:
            key = str(obj['Key'])
            if pattern in key:
                TotalFilesInSrcBucket.add(obj['Key'])
    print('Total files in Src Bucket -> ', len(TotalFilesInSrcBucket))
```

Comment: So you indicated a prefix of 2023-10-18?

Comment: So the prefix is the folder location inside the bucket because my s3 bucket structure is something like S3:/src/data/valid/

Comment: The pattern I indicated as 2023-10- to get all files for the month of October

Comment: S3 provides no other APIs to enumerate objects.  If you need something more bespoke, it might make sense to setup [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) that you can download and query fairly quickly instead of working through the page of objects.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not able to download these files due to security reasons, I just needed the names of the files to reference some other things. But the code above work but might just be a little slow running larger buckets. Thank you for that information tho

Comment: 4 minutes seems too long. Each API call to S3 can return up to 1000 objects. Therefore, it should only require 3 API calls. Can you check how many times your code looped through `page` to see whether it was a maximum of 3? Or were there more than 2400 objects in that Prefix, and your `pattern` only returned 2400?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate method would be to use the **resource** method of calling S3:

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
objects = s3.Bucket('name').objects.filter(Prefix='string')

for object in objects:
    if pattern in object.key:
        TotalFilesInSrcBucket.add(object.key)
```

The **resource** method handles the pagination for you.

See: [Bucket - Boto3 documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/index.html)

Comment: Let me give that a try. Thank You

Comment: For the line if pattern in key: would it instead by if pattern in object?

Comment: Oops! Changed to `if pattern in object.key`. The `object` variable is a dictionary containing many values.

Comment: Is there a way to start searching from the latest file. For example I have another scenario where there is a trillion files and it keeps getting added but I only want to return files that are basically the latest

Comment: Yes, there is a `StartAfter` parameter. The [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects_v2.html) says: _"StartAfter is where you want Amazon S3 to start listing from. Amazon S3 starts listing after this specified key. StartAfter can be any key in the bucket."_

Comment: I did try StartAfter parameter and it didn't work. I will revisit the documentation and try again. I did see this post saying something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54525484/boto3-list-objects-v2-startafter-does-not-work-correctly

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work" -- did it give an error, or did it return a result you think was incorrect?

Comment: So it didn't start at that start point that I defined. It was still getting all the results from the S3 buckets which I don't want. I defined StartAfter='2024-01' and was hoping that it will start listing all the S3 files from 2024-01. The file names have a date in front like 2024-01-15.filename.ndjson

Comment: Make sure `StartAfter` includes the **full key** of the object. So, it should specify: `StartAfter='src/data/valid/2024-01'`

Comment: I'll give that a shot, I thought since I already specified the Prefix I didn't need to. Thanks!

Comment: The reason is that the Key (filename) of an object **includes the full path**. There are actually no directories in S3 -- they are sort of displayed to make navigation easier and Prefixes cover most of their function, but think of filenames as the entire path and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank You! Understood now and after implementing the StartAfter, I think it had solved the issue. Took about 40min to go through 8million records which is so much faster than my initial of 8hrs. Thank You so much for your help!!!